# Advanced Custom Fields - All the input fields in my repeater object are disabled?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've got a flexible content field with multiple repeaters nested within. The flexible content is shown via conditional logic when a check box is checked.

For some reason all of the text fields in the repeaters are disabled. I didn't put the license key in before implementing these fields but I have now, so I can't see how that could cause an issue.

Any help would be appreciated, I've put in a support ticket but I haven't had any response for nearly a week.

If I delete the plugin and re-install I presume I would loose all my set-up fields?

Comment: I don't know what causes the issue, but you can export and import all set up fields, so you don't lose anything when reinstalling the plugin.

Comment: You do not have to export/import. The fields are still there when you install the plugin again. Did you solve the problem anyway?